# NSDateFormatter for rails 4.0 created_at

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails

Im trying to parse the created_at that rails returns, it looks like the following.

> 2013-09-08T09:18:45.500Z

Currently using

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"]
```

This doesn't work, the NSDate returns as nil.

Not sure how i should format after the last dot, hope i can get some help here!

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Capital "S" is for fractional seconds:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"]
```

You can find that (and much more!) in ["Appendix F: Date Format Patterns"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)
of the "Unicode Technical Standard #35: UNICODE LOCALE DATA MARKUP LANGUAGE".

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Works, will accept when im allowed, currently 6 minutes =). Ty for link, will check it out.